# Permanently set variable for ComboBox?

Tags: user-interface, combobox, updates, autoit

I'm trying to permanently update a ComboBox through my script. Let's say I have a combobox called

```
$myCombo = GUICtrlCreateCombo("Name", 296, 464, 169, 25)
```

and a button

```
$myButton = GUICtrlCreateButton("$000.00", 880, 380, 60, 20)
```

When my button is pressed, it creates a file named after whatever text is in my combo box.

```
; Pretend like this is in a loop
Case $myButton
    $nameFile = GUICtrlRead($myCombo)
    $file = $nameFile & ".csv"
    if NOT FileExists($file) then
        _FileCreate($file)
        FileOpen($File, 1)
        FileWriteLine ( $File, $nameFile)

        GUICtrlSetData($myCombo,$nameFile & "|")
    EndIf
```

This creates the file and updates the GUI to include the new text in the ComboBox, but I would like to permanently update the Combo. Is there a way to update it so it will have the new data even after exiting and restarting the script? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

have one file for having list of files created, prior your loop GUI loop

```
$cmbText = ""
$fileFileList = @ScriptDir & "\" & "filelist"
if FileExists($fileFileList) Then $cmbText = StringReplace(FileRead($fileFileList),@CRLF,"|")
GUICtrlSetData($myCombo,$cmbText)
```

Inside your loop, under your case statement, write the $nameFile in above used file filelist.

```
If NOT FileExists($fileFileList) then
  _FileCreate($fileFileList)
EndIf
FileWriteLine($fileFileList,$nameFile)
GUICtrlSetData($myCombo,$nameFile & "|")
```